# Put Show and Legend together in one plot

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have something like this in my script:

```
ms={3,4,6,8,9,11,13,15,20,100}
colors={Blue, Red, Purple, Black, Green, Yellow, Gray, LightGreen,LightGray, LightRed}
p= Range[1, 10];
p[[i]] = ListLinePlot[..., AxesLabel -> {"z","R"},PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]];
L = LineLegend[colors, ms, LegendLabel -> "title"]
```

EDIT:

Here you can find a full working example:

```
ms = {3, 4, 6}
colors = {Blue, Red, Purple}
p = Range[1, 3];
Dat = Range[1, 3];
Dat[[1]] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Dat[[2]] = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}};
Dat[[3]] = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}};
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, p[[i]] = ListLinePlot[Dat[[i]], AxesLabel -> {"z", "R"}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]];]
Show[p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]]
L = LineLegend[colors, ms, LegendLabel -> "title"]
```

I want to combine the last show with the legend.

I now want to combine the Legend with the ListLinePlots. Something like

```
Show[p[[1]],p[[2]],...,L]
```

Comment: A complete code will be more useful...

Comment: I have now edited the post with a fully working example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) function,

```
Legended[
  Show[p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]],
  LineLegend[colors, ms, LegendLabel -> "title"]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ms = {3, 4, 6};
colors = {Blue, Red, Purple};
```

Use indexed variable

```
Clear[Dat];

Dat[1] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Dat[2] = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}};
Dat[3] = {{1, 3}, {2, 4}};

ListLinePlot[Dat /@ Range[3],
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "R"},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotLegends -> ms]
```

[image]

Or use an array

```
Clear[Dat];

Dat = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
   {{1, 2}, {2, 5}},
   {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}};

ListLinePlot[Dat,
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "R"},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotLegends -> ms]
```